# How to obtain thumbnails for non-image files on OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

In my Windows Phone app, I'm referencing files in the user's OneDrive. When displaying those files in a list, I want to show thumbnails for the files. To do so, I'm using the "picture" attribute as provided by OneDrive.

However, it would appear that thumbnails are only provided by OneDrive for files that actually have any image content, e.g. a photo, a video, or an audio file with an embedded image. For audio files without embedded images or other files such as Word, no picture URL is provided.

Looking at the OneDrive app on Windows Phone, I can see that it does provide thumbnails for those sorts of files, but it is possible that the solution used is embedded icons for known filetypes.

I'm not looking for a discussion here but for a programming solution. If there isn't a straightforward way, e.g. a OneDrive API call, that will give me those thumbnails, I'm not going to worry about it as I do have a backup solution to the problem. I'm just trying to be as comprehensive as possible with how the files are handled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no interface to get thumbnail images on non-photo or non-video items on OneDrive via the LiveSDK.